# iPhone screenshot returning from background is all white

Tags: iphone, ios, opengl-es, multitasking

I am creating an iPhone game using OpenGL that works really well. I know that when the game go to background once the Home button is pressed iOS make a screenshot of the screen to be showed when the app returns to foreground.

The problem is that when you launch the game again (returning it from background) a white image is showed instead of the last screen of the game. Of course the game is working fine in the moment to go background.

I have tested this problem only with the simulator not with a real iPhone (Simulator v.5.0, iOS v.5.0).

Has anybody this problem and a solution for it? I am missing something?.

Update: I have found that some Cocos2D users [have the same problem but without a solution](http://www.cocos2d-iphone.org/forum/topic/8398). I don't use Cocos2D.

Update: I have checked that the snapshot taken by iOS is a 640x960 white jpg file. So maybe the problem is some type of connection between OpenGL-ES and the view of the game.

Comment: How are you capturing the screen shot? Please show us.

Comment: Jeshua I'm not capturing the screenshot, is the iOS system that take that screenshot automatically to be showed when the app become active again (to create a fast visual loading experience). That screenshot is showed all white instead of the last frame of the game.

Answer (score 1):

If your application is in OpenGL then you can use glReadPixels to read image screen.

```
- (UIImage*) getGLScreenshot {
    NSInteger myDataLength = 320 * 480 * 4;

    // allocate array and read pixels into it.
    GLubyte *buffer = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    glReadPixels(0, 0, 320, 480, GL_RGBA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, buffer);

    // gl renders "upside down" so swap top to bottom into new array.
    // there's gotta be a better way, but this works.
    GLubyte *buffer2 = (GLubyte *) malloc(myDataLength);
    for(int y = 0; y &lt;480; y++)
    {
        for(int x = 0; x &lt;320 * 4; x++)
        {
            buffer2[(479 - y) * 320 * 4 + x] = buffer[y * 4 * 320 + x];
        }
    }

    // make data provider with data.
    CGDataProviderRef provider = CGDataProviderCreateWithData(NULL, buffer2, myDataLength, NULL);

    // prep the ingredients
    int bitsPerComponent = 8;
    int bitsPerPixel = 32;
    int bytesPerRow = 4 * 320;
    CGColorSpaceRef colorSpaceRef = CGColorSpaceCreateDeviceRGB();
    CGBitmapInfo bitmapInfo = kCGBitmapByteOrderDefault;
    CGColorRenderingIntent renderingIntent = kCGRenderingIntentDefault;

    // make the cgimage
    CGImageRef imageRef = CGImageCreate(320, 480, bitsPerComponent, bitsPerPixel, bytesPerRow, colorSpaceRef, bitmapInfo, provider, NULL, NO, renderingIntent);

    // then make the uiimage from that
    UIImage *myImage = [UIImage imageWithCGImage:imageRef];
    return myImage;
}

- (void)saveGLScreenshotToPhotosAlbum {
    UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum([self getGLScreenshot], nil, nil, nil);
}
```